# Adding custom widget inside QTableWidget using pyside6

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I am trying to add my custom widgets into QTableWidget. It was getting added. Though its not visible properly. Below is my code snippet. I tried removing layout spaces in the widget code. It seems cell boundary and Qwidget has some spaces which I could not make it zero. Please show some light on this on how to fix this.

Main UI

```
custom_widget = PositionAddWidgets1()
self.tableWidget_position_sell.setCellWidget(row, 6, custom_widget)
```

Custom Widget class

```
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QSizePolicy, QVBoxLayout

class PositionAddWidgets1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.line_edit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.button1 = QPushButton("Add", self)
        self.button2 = QPushButton("1800", self)
        self.button3 = QPushButton("900", self)
        self.button4 = QPushButton("200", self)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2)
        layout.addWidget(self.button3)
        layout.addWidget(self.button4)

        self.setLayout(layout)
```

What I got the result is
[image]

Expected reulst is like below
[image]

Comment: What do you need `self.frame` for? You could just do `self.setLayout(layout)` and remove all reference to `self.frame` and `frame_layout`, no?

Comment: I tried without frame as well. Let me update my code without frame. That also similar output.

Comment: Well you'll need to do `layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)` when you clean your code; I hope that much was obvious though: `layout` just completely replaces `frame_layout`.

Comment: Awesome @Atmo ! setContentsMargins works for me. Pls post as ans! I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it should be enough to add:

```
layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
```

If that is still not enough or if you want to keep some of the margins for any reasons, you will have to set a minimum height for your widget. Add the below line and experiment what value works for you instead of `50`.

```
self.setMinimumHeight(50)
```

Alternatively, you could use a stylesheet on your table, again with some experimentation on the height you need:

```
self.tableWidget_position_sell.setStyleSheet('QTableView::item { min-height:50px; }')
```